# How can I recreate objects with Phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, phaserjs

How can I recreate the bomb when the add bomb function works?
when i click the addbomb I created in the top right of the screen, i want to regenerate the destroyed bomb item with the player's theme

```
var player, bomb, platform, keyboard, addbomb;
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("bootGame");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image("background", "./assets/ice.png");
    this.load.image("platform", "./assets/platform.png");
    this.load.image("snowman", "./assets/snowman.png");
    this.load.image("bomb", "./assets/war-bomb.png");
  }

  create() {
    this.add.image(0, 0, "background").setOrigin(0, 0);
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 100, "snowman");
    bomb = this.physics.add.sprite(500, 200, "bomb");

    addbomb = this.add.image(600, 100, "bomb").setInteractive();
    addbomb.inputEnabled = true;

    platform = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    platform.create(400, 500, "platform").setScale(2).refreshBody();

    this.physics.add.collider(player, platform);
    this.physics.add.collider(bomb, platform);
    this.physics.add.collider(player, bomb, temas, null, this);

    bomb.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    bomb.setBounce(1);

    keyboard = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    addbomb.on("pointerdown", function () {
      console.log("bomb_added");
    });

    function temas() {
      bomb.disableBody(true, true);
      console.log("collide:true");
    }
  }

  update() {
    bomb.setRotation(bomb.rotation + 0.15);
    bomb.body.setGravity(0, 200);

    if (keyboard.left.isDown) {
      player.setVelocityX(-150);
    } else if (keyboard.right.isDown) {
      player.setVelocityX(150);
    } else {
      player.setVelocityX(0);
    }

    if (keyboard.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
      player.setVelocityY(-150);
    }
  }
}

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 768,
  height: 512,
  backgroundColor: 0x22566,
  scale: {
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER,
  },
  scene: [Scene1],
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      gravity: {
        y: 100,
      },
    },
  },
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

I tried to write the same blocks of code inside the function but it didn't work. Then I tried var newbomb = new bomb and it didn't work. these were my most logical attempts, i didn't know how to search on the internet

Answer (score 0):

The fast/easy answer is to replace the click event handler and callback *(in the `create` function)* with the following lines of code:

```
...
addbomb.on("pointerdown", () => { // Watchout this is not an arrow function
   //console.log("bomb_added");
   let x = 100; // the position where the new bomb should spawn
   let y = 0; 
   let newBomb = this.physics.add.sprite(x, y, "bomb");
   this.physics.add.collider(newBomb , platform);
   this.physics.add.collider(player, newBomb, temas, null, this);
});
...
```

**Exrta**

*If you are planing on making a bigger game.*  You could use phaser groups, check out this [official example](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cgame%20objects%5Cgroup%5Ccreate%20child.js), or even better here the collection of [group releated examples](https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=game%20objects/group/&q=), if you want to know more about how groups can improve your game.

[This group example](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Cbullets%20group.js) fits be best for your specific problem/question, and showcases the creation of sprites *(in this specific case bullets on click)*